# Using a Javascript function to Return a value in a table element

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I need to display this result as a background image of my table.  I have added a function to the bottom of the javascript, but am unable to get it to pass thru. I removed the function it since it did not work.

This works as it is now, but does not put the image in the background.

Thanks.

```
<HTML>
<head><base href="http://localhost:85/shop/" target="_blank"></head>

<!--.<style>
divcurve
 {
border:1px solid;
 border-radius:5px;
 } 
</style>
-->
<style>
IMG {BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

 //Javascript Created by Computerhope http://www.computerhope.com
 //store the quotations in arrays

var images = [], 
index = 0;

images[0] = "<a href = '/shop/category.aspx/about/711/'><img src='/images/opc.png' alt='Tech Support' height='140' width='165'></a>";

images[1] = "<a href = '/shop/category.aspx/about/711/'><img src='/images/opd.png' alt='Barcode Help' height='140' width='165'></a>"; 

images[2] = "<a href = '/shop/category.aspx/about/711/'><img src='/images/opj.png' alt='Barcode Help' height='140' width='165'></a>";

images[3] = "<a href = '/shop/category.aspx/about/711/'><img src='/images/opg.png' alt='Barcode Help' height='140' width='165'></a>";

images[4] = "<a href = '/shop/category.aspx/about/711/'><img src='/images/opjb.png' alt='Barcode Help' height='140' width='165'></a>";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

document.write(images[index]);
//done
</script>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td width="20%>
<img src="/images/phone.gif">
</td>
<td width="70%">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: question is not clear .can you make a fiddle for this.

Comment: Cannot tell what you're asking.

Comment: Try just storing the url of each image in the array and then assigning that as the url of the `background-image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you mean, I may be wrong.

You want to select an image from an array containing strings of HTML which also happens to contain an image tag, you want to use the `src` attribute value for the background image of your table.

You would use a regular expression to do that in a for loop or join the array to a string first, could be used, but as Adam Botley mentioned, store each URL in the array, it will make your life a whole lot easier.

It looks like your code is from a tutorial, so if all you really want to do is randomly select a background image for the table that's even easier.

Here is what you can do. Create an array of URLs.

```
var urls = ['http://lorempixel.com/200/200', 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200'];
```

Then you need to calculate a random number to use for the key.

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length);
```

A [random number in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is floating point number between 0 and 1, so you multiply this by the amount of URLs in the array. The [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) returns the integer of the argument.

Then you'll need a reference to the table element.

```
var theTableElement = document.getElementById('theTableElement');
```

For that to actually work you must add an id to the table in the HTML.

```
<table id="theTableElement">
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>there</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>you</td>
    <td>person :)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, to set the background image, you can just.

```
theTableElement.style.background = 'url(' + urls[index] + ')';
```

Now It should work, let me know!

Comment: I appreciate your answer and the samples.  I do not work with JavaScript much, so even the simple stuff is difficult.  Ok I tried the code mentioned verbatim and got no result in the background.  I even used the document.write(urls[index]); to try and write the img out and it did not work either.  I also double checked the string to the images and it does work.

Comment: <html>
<head><base href="http://localhost:85/" target="_blank"></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = ['images/opc.png', 'images/opc.png'];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var theTableElement = document.getElementById('theTable');
theTableElement.style.backgroundImage = urls[index];

</script>
<table id="theTable">
<tr><td>testing to see if an image is behind<BR><BR><BR>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
If this works this should be at the bottom image above
</body>
</html>

Comment: The problem was that what I gave you, was untested :) Here is a [codepen](http://cdpn.io/BfmAe)

Comment: Yes it seems it was not working locally for some reason.  Your example was golden.  I of course added a typo that was an issue too.  I am using Notepad++ with a addin editor.  Is there a good free or close to free JavaScript editor you would recommend?   @Ben

Comment: [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is my weapon of choice. Try to get the beta. it is not free, but only asks for a key every once in a while.